# clip-path-polyfill react import not working

Tags: reactjs

Anyone know how to use this package with react?

npm package documentation - https://www.npmjs.com/package/clip-path-polyfill

The Code

```
import React from 'react';
import { Link } from 'react-scroll';
// import SvgBottomArrowCover from '../img/bottom-arrow-cover.svg';
import 'clip-path-polyfill.js'; // <------ ?????

function Intro() {
  return (
    <div id="intro">
      <div className="div-intro-background-window">
        <p>Greetings, my name is John Doe</p>
      </div>
      <Link
        activeClass="active"
        to={`about`}
        spy={true}
        smooth={true}
        offset={-80}
        duration={500}
        className="a-intro-bottom-click"
      >
        <div className="div-bouncing-arrow" />
        {/* <div className="div-intro-bottom" /> */}
        <div style={{position: "absolute", bottom: "0", width: "100%", height: "100%", backgroundColor: "#ffffff"}} data-polyclip="50%, 50%, 100%, 0, 100%, 100%, 0, 100%, 0,0" />
      </Link>
    </div>
  );
}

export default Intro;
```

The import and the last div are where I will need help understanding how to use this package. Unfortunately I could not find any actual code samples anywhere.

Answer (score 0):

```
import clipPathPolyfill from 'clip-path-polyfill/clip-path-polyfill';
```